# Swift: Catch event for Facebook Login via Facebook app

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, authentication

I have a FB login implemented in my app, it opens a WebView and if a user log in via WebView, everything is ok. Facebook will return results I can work with

Working code with WebView:

```
fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile","email"], from: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                    fbLoginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

However, if user does not log in via WebView, but select option to "Log in with the Facebook app", how can I get the result from Facebook app login?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. it appeared only when I use a custom login button
and call the logIn method of the FBSDKLoginManager

If I use :

```
let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.delegate = self
```

and

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
```

}

the problem is solved, I have the result from Facebook app login.

You can easily custom the FBSDKLoginButton.